# race condition between C++ stream's flush() and FindFirstFileEx()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, iostream

My code looks close to this:

1. Lots of writes using normal C++ IO stream insertions like `steram << "foo";`
2. `stream.flush();` at some point;
3. MSVC C API's [`_stat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) call right after the flush above.

What I am observing is that the `_stat()` call is returning sizes different from `stream.tellp()`, smaller sizes.

If I close the `stream` before calling the `_stat()` function it returns correct results. I have stepped into the `_stat()` and it uses [`FindFirstFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the size.

Is this a known Win32 API quirk?

Comment: Is it possible that stream.flush() is asynchronous and returns before the buffer is flushed?

Comment: You should check by FileMon, which operations are performed by your calls. If, by accident, they use FASTIO_WRITE instead of IRP_MJ_WRITE, then your code implicitly uses intermediate buffer of FASTIO. Perhaps you can enforce a fallback to IRP programmatically, but this will slow down writing process.

Comment: This is by design for the NTFS file system and not an api quirk.  The attributes in the directory record do not reflect the actual file properties until all handles to the file are closed.  Not just for the file size, also the timestamp values.

Comment: @HansPassant: Would I get more accurate information if I used  `GetFileAttributesEx()` instead of `_stat()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working on Windows Vista or higher. The file size was updated in the file attributes under XP every time the file was flushed to disc. This is no longer true on Vista where as Hans already did comment the file attributes and its size is updated when the last handle to the file is closed.

See [Old New Thing Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx) for more details.

You could try to open the file a second time and close it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the blog. It explains things a lot. Though it seems to me this is a bug in `_stat()` then that it uses a function that could potentially get me stale data.

Comment: That is not the only quirk. Windows has a feature called File System Tunneling which does report the same file size for a certain amount of time. This does surface if you e.g. log to a file, close, rename it and open a file with the same name again. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx

Comment: Ugh. This looks like unreasonable attempt to please lazy or bad coders. If I wanted files to have same time stamps I would have taken care of it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use GetFileInformationByHandle to get exact size.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the file system caching. From the C++ stream's point of view, it has passed all written data to the physical device, as required by the standard. But the file system might cache writes, and flush them according to some other policy.

A possible solution would be to use on of the following Win32 API options:

1. If you happen to open the file yourself, using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flags.
2. When you're done writing, call [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ensure metadata is flushed (you'll have to somehow obtain the file's handle for that).

This shouldn't hurt performance too much, assuming your C++ stream is doing its own buffering.

Comment: Shouldn't the system ensure consistency between its internal data structures? I have actually redone the code so that it does `stream.close()` before the `_stat()` call so now it works.

Comment: @wilx, consistency comes at a price. Caching works much better without ensuring consistency, therefore it is up to you to say which is more important for your application. I'm glad you solved your problem, would be interesting to see if my suggestions solve it as well.

Comment: Sure but consistency and correctness is significantly more important than speed.

Comment: @wilx, if that were always true, you wouldn't have C++ buffered streams. You do have them because they are faster, and safe in the absence of races. If races are possible, you have synchronization means you must use. Same goes with the level below: you get the speed by default, and "manual" means for maintaining consistency.